# How does a non-forking web server work?

Tags: algorithm

Non-forking (aka single-threaded or `select()`-based) webservers like lighttpd or nginx are
gaining in popularity more and more.

While there is a multitude of documents explaining forking servers (at 
various levels of detail), documentation for non-forking servers is sparse.

I am looking for a **bird eyes** view of **how** a **non-forking web server works**.
(Pseudo-)code or a state machine diagram, stripped down to the bare 
minimum, would be great.

I am aware of the following resources and found them helpful.

> - [The
>     World of SELECT()](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html)
> - [thttpd
>     source code](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd)
> - [Lighttpd
>     internal states](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs:InternalHTTPStates)

However, I am interested in the principles, not implementation details.

Specifically:

- Why is this type of server sometimes called non-blocking, when `select()` essentially blocks?
- Processing of a request can take some time. What happens with new requests during this time when there is no specific listener thread or process? Is the request processing somehow interrupted or time sliced?

**Edit:**
As I understand it, while a request is processed (e.g file read or CGI script run) the
server cannot accept new connections. Wouldn't this mean that such a server could miss a lot
of new connections if a CGI script runs for, let's say, 2 seconds or so?

Comment: I'd think that a non-forking web server would be a bad match to any web server that wanted to server more than a trivial amount of dynamic content.

Comment: @Eddie Not in the least. With n processors, having more than n threads isn't going to allow you to do more work. A properly designed asynchronous server can do just as much work as a forking or threaded one.

Comment: @Nick Johnson:  It depends.  If you have N processors and N threads, to the extent that any one request blocks waiting for I/O, you're not actually using your processor unless you create more threads.  For example, if you have to go to the database to satisfy a dynamic request, that thread is stopped until you get a response. With only N threads, you may spend most of your time waiting and only a small amount of your time actually processing.

Comment: @Eddie That was more or less my point. Non-forking (non-blocking) servers avoid blocking at all costs - which is why they scale just fine, as long as they have as many threads as processors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic pseudocode:

```
setup
while true
    select/poll/kqueue
    with fd needing action do
        read/write fd
        if fd was read and well formed request in buffer
            service request
        other stuff
```

- Though `select()` & friends block, socket I/O is not blocking. You're only blocked until you have something fun to do.
- Processing individual requests normally involved reading a file descriptor from a file (static resource) or process (dynamic resource) and then writing to the socket. This can be done handily without keeping much state.
- So `service request` above typically means opening a file, adding it to the list for `select`, and noting that stuff read from there goes out to a certain socket. Substitute FastCGI for file when appropriate.

EDIT:

- Not sure about the others, but nginx has 2 processes: a master and a worker. The master does the listening and then feeds the accepted connection to the worker for processing.

Answer (score 4):

**select() PLUS nonblocking I/O** essentially allows you to manage/respond to multiple connections as they come in a single thread (**multiplexing**), versus having multiple threads/processes handle one socket each.  The goal is to minimize the ratio of server footprint to number of connections.

It is efficient because this single thread takes advantage of the high level of active socket connections required to reach saturation (since we can do nonblocking I/O to multiple file descriptors).

The rationale is that it takes very little time to acknowledge bytes are available, interpret them, then decide on the appropriate bytes to put on the output stream.  The actual I/O work is handled without blocking this server thread.

This type of server is always waiting for a connection, by blocking on select().  Once it  gets one, it handles the connection, then revisits the select() in an infinite loop. In the simplest case, this server thread does NOT block any other time besides when it is setting up the I/O.

If there is a second connection that comes in, it will be handled the next time the server gets to select().  At this point, the first connection could still be receiving, and we can start sending to the second connection, from the very same server thread. This is the goal.

Search for "[multiplexing network sockets](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=multiplexing+network+sockets)" for additional resources.

Or try Unix Network Programming by Stevens, Fenner, Rudoff